# destructing an object being function's argument with default property

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

I want to pass an object as an argument to the function. If property 'prop' of this  object is undefined, it should be initialized by default value.

How to do it using modern JS?

I expect something like this:

```
const fun = function(options = { prop: 'default'}) { console.log(options.prop)}


fun({a: 'x', prop: 'hello'}) ... // log: 'hello'

fun({a: 'x'}) ... // log: 'default'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to destructure in the parameter list, you won't have access to the *entire* original object (the `options`, here) anymore - you'll only have the destructured variables. So, leave out the `options =` part, and put the `=` after the `prop`, instead of `:`. For example:

```js
const fun = function({ prop = 'default', a }) {
  console.log('prop:', prop, 'a:', a);
};

fun({
  a: 'x',
  prop: 'hello'
}) // log: 'hello'

fun({
  a: 'x'
}) // log: 'default'
```

If the function also may not be called with any parameters, you may default-assign an empty object:

```js
const fun = function({ prop = 'default', a } = {}) {
  console.log('prop:', prop, 'a:', a);
};

fun({
  a: 'x',
  prop: 'hello'
}) // log: 'hello'

fun({
  a: 'x'
}) // log: 'default'

fun(); // log: 'default'
```

Comment: so, that means i have no access to 'a' property anymore?

Comment: You can destructure as many properties as you want, just add them to the inside of the `{}`

Comment: @CertainPerformance is there a way to avoid error when `null` is passed in to `fun` function?

Comment: @TheReason Default parameters only work when no argument or `undefined` is passed. If a non-undefined, non-object may be passed (for example, `null` or some primitive), then you'll have to check for that *outside* of the parameter list, and *then* destructure the argument or default object.

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax instead:

```js
const fun = ({ prop = "default" }) => console.log(prop);
fun({ a: "x", prop: "hello" });
fun({ a: "x" });
```

Note that you will lose the object, and only have access to `prop`. To solve this, you can collect the rest of the properties and expand them into an object:

```js
const fun = ({ prop = "default", ...rest }) => {
  console.log(prop);
  const otherProps = { ...rest };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(otherProps));
}
fun({ a: "x", prop: "hello" });
fun({ a: "x" });
fun({ a: "x", b: "nonexistent", c: true, prop: "Hi!" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rest properties and exclude `prop` from the object, take the value or default and assign this value back to the object.

```js
const
    fun = function({ prop = 'default', ...options }) { 
        Object.assign(options, { prop });
        console.log(options.prop);
    };

fun({ a: 42 });
fun({ a: 42, prop: 'bar' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to handle this inside the function itself. Below is the code which will work for your particular scenario

```
var fun = function(options = { prop:'default'}) {
if(options.prop == undefined){
options.prop = 'default'
}
console.log(options.prop)
}

fun({a:'hello'})// logs: default
```